How to "select all" and copy dmesg in "terminal"?
Is there a away to "select all" in "terminal"?
I have a large "dmesg" and like to copy it for further analysis.
"standard" - "use mouse"  takes too long to highlight the entire text.

dmesg > outputfile and then examine that outputfile with whichever tool you'd like.

Or sudo dmesg | gedit - The dash at the end is important.

This question is similar to: How to redirect output to screen as well as a file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
